# codename one webBrowser external link

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to view an external website into a web browser component. It works in emulator but when I build to Android it seem there is lack of internet permission. Can anyone help me where I wrong?

```
    Form form = new Form();
    form.setTitle("");
    form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.setURL("http://www.google.com/");
    Container container = new Container();
    container.addComponent(wb);
    form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, container);
    form.show();﻿
```

[image: Take a look]

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the WebBrowser in a flowlayout container which might be problematic.
Try to place it in a border layout container center instead:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.setURL("http://www.google.com/");
Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
container.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);
form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, container);
```

Comment: Layout doesn't support adding with arguments: com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout
 at com.codename1.ui.layouts.Layout.addLayoutComponent(Layout.java:64)
 at com.codename1.ui.Container.addComponent(Container.java:448)
 at com.codename1.ui.Form.addComponent(Form.java:1026)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:46)

Comment: notice I changed also this line: Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());

Comment: Yes but it not works. I removed also last borderlayout.center but android screen is blank yet

Comment: Did you place the web browser component DIRECTLY in the form where its in a `BorderLayout` using the add version that accepts center? That will work. The web browser is working but it sizing to 0  on the device.